# Google places api does not work after using google map api v2

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

As google has updated its map api, i have implemented this new Google Maps api V2. My map appears in my app but places are not shown on my android map. when i debug my code, at one point in my code it said "access denied" for places api. I have used my new map api key in places api code.

Can anyone guide me in this regard?

Comment: Did you switch on the Google Places in the [API Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/)?

Comment: I was using google maps api and places api previously. then i changed to Google maps api v2. but now my nearby restaurants do not appear on map. when i turn on places api, it asks me for website url and company but i want to use it in my android app not in website.

Comment: Did you try to turn it on? I am not quite sure, but maybe the website url is only needed for registration.

Comment: i did but it still does not show places on map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just looked into my code and found out the following:

I use a different key for the Google Places calls. It is **not** the Google Maps key. In the Google API console on the page "API Access" it is called

> Key for browser apps (with referers)

I append this key to the URL of my Places API calls. These calls are done over HTTP. I am not sure if there is a different way to get the places.

Try to generate this kind of key and use this for your app.

Comment: where to append that key. i ma passing "location,radius,types,keys and sensor"?

Comment: See this example: [Google Places API - Places Search](http://ddewaele.blogspot.de/2011/05/introducing-google-places-api.html)